# Bump substrate's dependency from 3.0.0 to master branch for a running solo chain?

Tags: storage

We have a running solo chain that is based on the officially released 3.0.0 version. Is there any guide or example about bumping dependency from 3.0.0 to the latest master branch? Any PRs we should pay attention to that might break the running solo chain, such as state migration or consensus change?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing stopping you from migrating to the latest master, even better is to migrate to the [latest polkadot release branch](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/polkadot-v0.9.27), depending on how often you are planning to upgrade and how much you care about the release having been tested.

Your old WASM runtime should be running fine on that, when it comes to upgrading the runtime itself - this would really depend on the pallets you are using and their versions. A variety of pallets might have one or several migrations that you have to execute one after another depending on how far up you want to go with the version.

The best way to determine those is just looking at any of the pallets that you are about to upgrade along with the runtime and apply all the migrations as needed.

In order to further bullet-proof your runtime migrations - please take a look at [this tool](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/command-line-tools/try-runtime/). And a crowdcast seminar from one of the links [here](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/try_runtime_cli/index.html#resources).

Comment: Thanks! Let me clarify my understanding and please correct me if I misunderstand anything.
1. New polkadot host should be campatiable with the old wasm. The consensus part would not be break.
2. I can use the `try-runtime` tool to check the storage migration.

Comment: Indeed, those are all correct.